# Store and fetch the image from MongoDB using node.js and show it trough RestFulAPI

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to Node.js and I am trying to store the image to monodb and I have successfully uploaded the image to mongodb but I am unable to show that image on PostMaster using RESTfulAPI below is my code to insert image to mon

```
logger.info('result inforamtion'  +result);

 var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(parsedResponse);



         var arrayOfImages = [];

          if (result.images.length>0) {

 for (var i = 0; i <result.images.length ; i++) {


           var newImg = result.images[i].toString();



           var encImg = newImg.toString('base64');
           var newItem = {
                           date: Date(), 
                           contentType: 'image/png',
                           img: new Buffer(encImg, 'base64')
                         };

              var ObjDetails = {
                                particularDevId : result.deviceID,
                                images : newItem
                               };

              arrayOfImages.push(ObjDetails);

 }
 var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayOfImages));
//console.log(parsedResponse);
      mongodb.saveMany('deviceImages',arrayOfImages,function(err,resultImage){
          if (err) {
                   res.send({"status":0,"message":"error in insertion of the record"});
                  }
          else
             {
                  res.json(resultImage);




        var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resultImage[0].images.img));
console.log(parsedResponse);

             }
           });
          }
          else
          {
            logger.info('No images available in the body');
          }
```

in the I am getting response as

> [
>       {
>           "particularDevId": "1234",
>           "images": {
>               "date": "Wed Aug 30 2017 15:53:23 GMT+0530 (IST)",
>               "contentType": "image/png",
>               "img": {
>                   "type": "Buffer",
>                   "data": [
>                       161,
>                       184,
>                       222,
>                       114,
>                       211,
>                       155,
>                       141,
>                       231,
>                       45
>                   ]
>               }
>           },
>           "_id": "59a6921b79106508be4a4a10"
>       }
>   ]

I am trying to display that image on postmaster so that I can see that image but I when I try to fetch the images data(buffer) using below code I am getting empty white page

```
                res.contentType(result.images.contentType);
              //  res.send(result.images.date);
              var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.images.img.buffer));
console.log(parsedResponse);
                res.send(parsedResponse);
```

Can someone please help me how to show send the image in response so that I can view that image in postmaster or browser??

Comment: I recommend against storing images in the database at all. Put them in cheap storage (eg S3) and store the URL in the database

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply could you please give some sample code for creating a URL for an image as I am new to Node.js.So could you please provide me with some code.